# 17.10 with Intel HD 5500 freezes when secondary monitor is plugged in

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.10, intel-graphics

Ubuntu 17.10 with Intel HD 5500  (Toshiba Z 30) freezes when secondary monitor is plugged in.

`dmesg` output:

```
[ 1131.717318] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1176 at /build/linux-cg_do7/linux-4.13.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:12848 intel_atomic_commit_tail+0xfa7/0xfb0 [i915]
[ 1131.717319] Modules linked in: rfcomm cmac bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic dm_crypt intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal arc4 intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc snd_soc_rt5640 snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus iwlmvm snd_pcm_dmaengine aesni_intel mac80211 snd_seq_midi aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd snd_seq_midi_event intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf iwlwifi input_leds snd_rawmidi uvcvideo joydev videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops cfg80211 serio_raw videobuf2_v4l2 lpc_ich videobuf2_core wmi_bmof rtsx_pci_ms snd_hda_codec_realtek memstick snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic videodev snd_hda_intel media snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mei_me toshiba_acpi snd_seq sparse_keymap mei snd_pcm
[ 1131.717358]  toshiba_bluetooth shpchp toshiba_haps industrialio snd_seq_device snd_timer tpm_infineon snd soundcore mac_hid spi_pxa2xx_platform dw_dmac snd_soc_sst_acpi dw_dmac_core snd_soc_sst_match 8250_dw parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 psmouse i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea ahci sysfillrect libahci sysimgblt fb_sys_fops e1000e rtsx_pci drm ptp pps_core wmi sdhci_acpi video sdhci
[ 1131.717386] CPU: 0 PID: 1176 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.13.0-38-generic #43-Ubuntu
[ 1131.717387] Hardware name: TOSHIBA PORTEGE Z30-B/PORTEGE Z30-B, BIOS Version 3.20   04/09/2015
[ 1131.717389] task: ffff8cc4cd66dd00 task.stack: ffffa24701d6c000
[ 1131.717425] RIP: 0010:intel_atomic_commit_tail+0xfa7/0xfb0 [i915]
[ 1131.717427] RSP: 0018:ffffa24701d6f880 EFLAGS: 00010282
[ 1131.717429] RAX: 000000000000001c RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000000
[ 1131.717430] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000002 RDI: 0000000000000246
[ 1131.717431] RBP: ffffa24701d6f938 R08: 000000000000001c R09: 00000000000033b8
[ 1131.717432] R10: ffffa24701d6f880 R11: 0000000000000a25 R12: 0000000000005df1
[ 1131.717433] R13: ffff8cc4c3630000 R14: ffff8cc4c46bb000 R15: 0000000000000003
[ 1131.717435] FS:  00007faf81239500(0000) GS:ffff8cc4e1400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1131.717437] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1131.717438] CR2: 00007f19be520000 CR3: 000000040d9a2004 CR4: 00000000003606f0
[ 1131.717439] Call Trace:
[ 1131.717447]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[ 1131.717480]  intel_atomic_commit+0x3d5/0x490 [i915]
[ 1131.717499]  ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x37e/0x540 [drm]
[ 1131.717512]  drm_atomic_commit+0x51/0x60 [drm]
[ 1131.717522]  restore_fbdev_mode+0x15e/0x270 [drm_kms_helper]
[ 1131.717529]  drm_fb_helper_restore_fbdev_mode_unlocked+0x2e/0x80 [drm_kms_helper]
[ 1131.717535]  drm_fb_helper_set_par+0x2d/0x60 [drm_kms_helper]
[ 1131.717572]  intel_fbdev_set_par+0x1a/0x70 [i915]
[ 1131.717575]  ? fb_set_var+0x259/0x440
[ 1131.717577]  fb_set_var+0x19f/0x440
[ 1131.717580]  ? __update_load_avg_se.isra.37+0x155/0x160
[ 1131.717582]  ? update_load_avg+0x426/0x5a0
[ 1131.717585]  ? update_curr+0x7a/0x1b0
[ 1131.717589]  fbcon_blank+0x2b7/0x3a0
[ 1131.717593]  ? __switch_to+0x13a/0x540
[ 1131.717598]  do_unblank_screen+0xba/0x1b0
[ 1131.717601]  complete_change_console+0x59/0xe0
[ 1131.717604]  vt_ioctl+0x1162/0x11a0
[ 1131.717607]  tty_ioctl+0xf6/0x8b0
[ 1131.717611]  ? generic_file_write_iter+0xf4/0x1f0
[ 1131.717614]  ? new_sync_write+0xe7/0x140
[ 1131.717618]  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa8/0x630
[ 1131.717621]  SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[ 1131.717626]  entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x24/0xab
[ 1131.717627] RIP: 0033:0x7faf7e688ef7
[ 1131.717629] RSP: 002b:00007fff43178818 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
[ 1131.717631] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000005 RCX: 00007faf7e688ef7
[ 1131.717632] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000005605 RDI: 000000000000000b
[ 1131.717633] RBP: 00007fff431782f0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000001
[ 1131.717634] R10: 00007fff431787cc R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000000000000002e
[ 1131.717635] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 000055f8a16b1290 R15: 00007faf7e9558a0
[ 1131.717637] Code: ff ff ff 48 83 c7 08 e8 f8 7e 70 c8 4c 8b 85 70 ff ff ff 4d 85 c0 0f 85 76 fa ff ff 8d 73 41 48 c7 c7 b0 45 69 c0 e8 aa 32 72 c8 <0f> ff e9 60 fa ff ff 66 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 57 41
```

What might be the problem ?